# how to resolve 500 error on server ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got this error message when I tested my website on remote server.

```
 POST https:mywebsiteLink/businessLayer/issueTickets.php 500()
 send @ jquery.min.js:4
 ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
 issueTickets @weeklyRegisteration.php:58
 onsubmit @ weeklyRegisteration.php:161
```

My ajax code is:

```
function issueTickets() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "businessLayer/issueTickets.php",
            data: $('#weeklyRegisterationForm').serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                    if(data.indexOf("class='msg') > -1){
                        $("#errMsg").html(data);
                        $("#center").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
                    }else{
                        location.href = "tickets.php";
                    }
            },
            error:function (){}
            });
            return false;
        }
```

And here is the form that call this function:

```
<form action="weeklyRegisteration" method="post" id="weeklyRegisterationForm" onsubmit="return issueTickets();">

    </form>
```

The jQuery.min.js error starts here at the :

```
g.setRequestHeader(f,d[f]+"");g.send(b.hasContent&&b.data||null),c=fu
```

The error is on calling the php file that has the business logic for producing the tickets:

[image]

Here is the php code that should be return as response:

```
if(!empty($tickets)){
            //set session variable
            $_SESSION['tickets'] = $tickets;
            $_SESSION['preTicketMsg'] = $preTicketMsg;
            exit();
        }
```

The code is working fine on local host, but is not on web host.

**NOTE: I can not check the server log since my account on web host is free.**

How I can solve this issue?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider, there is **nothing** we can do without knowing what is in the server logs.

Comment: http 500 is `internal server error` and not issue with client side code... can you check if the server is working as expected.
Also, try using applications like `postman` https://www.getpostman.com/apps for testing the server first

Comment: `500` means error is at server.

Comment: OK. Thank you all.

Comment: @Nikhil Motiani  could I use postman to submit the form and check the ajax error?

Comment: Use postman or just try to hit that PHP file in your browser to see if it gives a response